# Infinite loop on animation

Tags: css, animation, fadein

Okay so I have a never ending loop that I just want to happen 1 time right at the start of loading the site.

```
-webkit-animation: BG-fade-in 2s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
-moz-animation:    BG-fade-in 2s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
-o-animation:      BG-fade-in 2s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
animation:         BG-fade-in 2s infinite; /* IE 10+ */
```

Comment: Change animation-iteration-count: infinite; to animation-iteration-count: 1; or, as in your case, delete the infinite value since the default value is 1.

Comment: I have no idea what just happened here :-O.

Answer (score 1):

I'll post my comment as an answer so you get the option to accept it if you want.

Change `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` to `animation-iteration-count: 1;`.
Or as in your case, you can just delete the `infinite` value since the default value is `1`.